# Where is HttpRequest.InputStream read from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

I have several applications hosted on the same web server, and for short periods of time they appear to pause, for want of a better description. I should probably point out that at no point do i see a memory or CPU spike on this server, and disk latency isn't a problem.

Each application may work slightly differently, but a clean example to show the problem would be:

```
public partial class Listener : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

        if (Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST")
        {
            //...
            Response.Write(Tools.WrapError("Request type was not POST - Page Loaded in browser?"));
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
                string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

... and so on...
```

The problem I am seeing is that reading the stream can take up to 10 seconds, to read 20-50 bytes.

When this happens, i see very similar behaviour across the various applications, so my questions are...

1. Where is 'Request.InputStream'? Am I reading this from RAM, or straight from the network?
2. Is there something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm doing this? I don't think I am, since most of the time this process takes only a few ms and as I said, some of the apps are slightly different. 
   For instance this app is a simple web page, but another implements the  IHttpHandler interface, using 'xmlDoc.Load(Context.Request.InputStream);' to read the input stream.

Comment: It depends on whether Request.Form or Request.Files or some other function which requires parsing the uploaded data had been invoked or not. If not, you should be reading directly from the network. But if your page has any asp controls, the form is probably already read because before page_load view state is at least parsed. What does your aspx contains? For an http handler, it is probably directly read from the network, see buffered and buffer less input streams also.

Comment: To confirm, there are no controls on the asp page, the actual markup only contains reference to the codebehind. Thank you for clarification

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. You must have a network related issue at those times since all of the applications are affected. We have logs showing the upload durations using the InputStream in an HttpModule and usually most of the duration seems to be spent reading the posted content

Comment: Unfortunately this is in a hosted cloud environment, and the hosting company are refusing to acknowledge an issue may exist. Still, thank you for looking over my problem

Comment: You are welcome and wish you good luck with that